# Is it possible to run rails g controller/model in a test mode, to see what will happen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know before hand exactly what files a generator will create, is it possible to run it in a 'test' mode so it just lists the files and doesn't actually create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use the -p option

```
ctcherry$ rails g
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

ctcherry$ rails g controller controllername -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I know you can create the controller/model and then turn around and destroy it. Rails will undo everything it just did.

```
$ rails new my_app

$ cd my_app/

$ rails g controller SomeName
  create  app/controllers/some_name_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/some_name
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/functional/some_name_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/some_name_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/helpers/some_name_helper_test.rb

$ rails destroy controller SomeName
  remove  app/controllers/some_name_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  remove    app/views/some_name
  invoke  test_unit
  remove    test/functional/some_name_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  remove    app/helpers/some_name_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/unit/helpers/some_name_helper_test.rb
```

HTH

Comment: And then there's what @ctcherry just posted :)

Comment: true, but the destroy command also comes in handy, thanks for the tip!